# How to see which Atribute (Feature) contribute most to the performance of the classification with PCA in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka, pca

I would like to perform classification on a small data set 65x9 using some of the Machine Learning Classification Methods (SVM, Decision Trees or any other).
So, before starting with the classification I would like to do attribute analyses with PCA in Matlab or Weka (preferred MatLab). I would like to obtain which Attribute contribute most to the performance of the classifier. So I can maybe reduce the number of some Attribute or/and include more in the future. Any example of PCA can find regarding this in MatLab or Weka?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PCA is a unsupervised feature extraction method.

If your question is on selecting attributes to use with PCA, i don't know what your purpose is but it is unnecessary to do something like that to improve classification performance. Just use the whole attributes. PCA will give you best attributes in decreasing order for each instance.

If your question is on selecting attributes after PCA, you can chose a treshold (for example 0.95) and calculate #attributes enough for treshold beginning from the first attribute to last one. You can use the eigenvalues of covariance matrix to calculate and achive treshold in PCA.

After running PCA, we know that the first attribute is the best one, the second attribute is the best one after first etc...

Comment: Thanks. Just a comment when I use the pca function in Matlab do I need to include the labels (classes) or only data file is attributes and instances (without labels)?

Comment: As PCA is unsupervised method, it doesn't use the class(label) information. You don't need to include labels. If you include, they just will work like another feature. I can offer LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) instead of PCA, if you have labels too.

Comment: I have labels too. Whats is than the difference between LDA and PCA?

Comment: LDA uses the class(label) information so that it can take similarities within-class and between-class into account. You can google LDA for implementation details. LDA can produce better performance than PCA if labels are present.

Comment: so after LDA u can perform classification and achieve improvement of the classification performance?I LDA part of Matlab toolbox so I can just use some MatLab precompile function?

Comment: Is there some precompile LDA Matlab function or do I need to write own code?

Comment: You need to write your own code or google for a matlab implementation of LDA. Normal LDA is a machine learning technique; so, i don't think there is built-in support of Matlab.